# What happens to existing Firebase Auth users if multi tenancy is enabled?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

I am considering enabling multiple tenancy on an existing app that uses Firebase Authentication, having read this https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-authentication

What I'm not clear on and therefore worried about, is what happens to my existing app users once I add a new tenant?  Will they be unable to login unless I migrate them to some "default" tenant?

I haven't found any assurance or explanation in the docs, so maybe its ok, but I don't want to click that button unless I am sure.  And is there any way to back out of enabling multi tenancy in the event of a disaster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the absence of any reassurance, I just went ahead and clicked the button.  Nothing bad happened to my existing users.  They were migrated from Firebase authentication to GCP Identify Platform, under the context of the project, which runs along side tenants it seems.

Then I was free to make another tenant, which formed an entirely separate space to configure providers and house user identity.